# What does this statement pertaining to fission mean?

Tags: reproduction, meiosis, mitosis, cell-division, asexual-reproduction

I was reading about [fission on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fission_(biology)) when I encountered the following statement under *Fission of prokaryotes* section.

> Like in mitosis (and unlike in meiosis), the parental identity is lost.

**What does 'parental identity' mean here?**

From what I understand it to be, it possibly means that the parental form is no longer present after mitosis as it is divided to form new individuals in the process, thus the 'parental identity' is lost. If I am right, isn't parental identity lost in meiosis also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, this makes no sense or at least is misleading. It seems the edit was introduced in March 2019, after another mistaken edit that suggested parental identity *was* preserved in binary fission.

I agree with Douglas that this phrase "parental identity" seems to have been invented in some study guide, so I wouldn't dwell on it. It does not seem to be used by scientists in science. From context, though, they seem to intend to distinguish with [budding](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Budding), where you can clearly identify one cell as the (larger) "parent", and the other distinctly as a "daughter" copy. You can tell which one is the parent, aka, "parent identity" is preserved. In binary fission, there is no such asymmetry, and you can't really consider either cell the "parent" of the other.

With respect to meiosis, the editor may have been thinking of [genetic imprinting](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genomic_imprinting) where the parent is marked in gametes epigenetically, but this doesn't have much to do with "parental identity" in terms of cell division. The only similarly is that people do use "parental identity" to refer to chromosomes marked by whether they came from the female or male parent. I think the author just got confused by reading that term in two places, not realizing the meaning was totally different, and trying to make sense of the two together. Wikipedia is great and I rely on it a lot as a basic reference that anyone can use, but this is one of the occasional examples where it falls short!

Answer (score 1):

#### In fission, each daughter cell gets a full copy of the parental genome. But "parental identity" doesn't seem to be a standard term.

> **What does 'parental identity' mean here?**

You're not alone; I don't get it either. At first, I assumed it was jargon specific to molecular biology or microbiology.
But, *parental identity* doesn't appear to be a standard term in biology.
A [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22parental+identity%22+biology) returns exclusively online study guides, textbook exercise answers, and [your own question :)](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/107990/what-does-this-statement-pertaining-to-fission-mean)

> From what I understand it to be, it possibly means that the parental form is no longer present after mitosis as it is divided to form new individuals in the process, thus the 'parental identity' is lost.

Though I don't know what exactly was intended, I think the author meant the genetic material, not the cell body. That is, "parental identity" is said to be "preserved" if the daughter cell contains a complete copy of the parent cell's genome.

> If I am right, isn't parental identity lost in meiosis also?

In both cases, the cell bodies are split -- so, yes.
But meiosis results in very different genetics.

In both fission and mitosis, each daughter cell (2 total) retains a complete copy of the parent cell's genome. But in meiosis, each daughter cell (4 total) retains only half parent cell's genome.
(This distinction is the [*ploidy*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ploidy) of the cells.)